# GitLab rss feed for a specific repository - button not working

Tags: rss, gitlab

I am trying to get the url for one of my group repository on GitLab.
I have found in the activity page of the repo. a rss button on the top right, but it doesn't seem to work. How do I get to work? 
*I don't any paid plan with gitlab.
*The repository is presently private, but will eventually become public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is an existing one that has been fixed. 
See issue [#45398](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/45398)
The fix is merged to master, but not yet available.

Here the temporary fix I found is to inspect the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, select the rss feed button 
(it won't exactly be it and this is the problem)
In the right tab that opened, you will find a `div` element with `class="controls"`, expand it and find the rss feed link.